# Авторизация и сессии

Tags: веб-программирование, php, пароль, сессия, авторизация

Подскажите, как в наше время делают авторизацию и где хранят сессии. Давно не занимался сайтами, возможно отстал от прогресса.

Собственно:

- Храню пароль в виде `md5($salt.$pass.$salt)`. Вроде их уже легко ломают?
- `sessionhash=md5(uniqid(microtime()))`;
- Сессии хранятся в таблице `MySQL` в `sissionid, userid, sessionhash`
- `sissionid` и `sessionhash` отдаются в куках.

Как сейчас это делается?

Answer (score 1):

Данные, хранящиеся на стороне пользователя, надо зашифровать ключом, хранящимся на сервере.
Тут это разбирается на примере ***Node.JS*** и для PHP: [Раз](http://habrahabr.ru/company/nordavind/blog/196018/) и [Два](http://toster.ru/q/59290)

Answer (score 1):

По пункту 1:

В настоящее время существуют очень эффективные реализации перебора хэшей. Поэтому даже длинные пароли, подвергнутые однократному хэшированию, перестали быть безопасными.

В версии `php 5.5` реализован алгоритм [`PBKDF2`](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2). Его рекомендууется использовать для получения устойчивых хэшей.  `http://php.net/manual/ru/function.hash-pbkdf2.php`.

Answer (score 1):

Советую посмотреть в сторону фреймворка CodeIgniter. Всё удобно, защищено и очень просто. + Есть библиотека аутентификации и регистрации.

Comment: кодигнитер - шкура мамонта, оставшаяся еще с прошлого тысячелетия

> Всё удобно, защищено и очень просто.

https://www.google.ru/search?q=codeigniter%20vulnerability

Я уж молчу о том, что защищенными обычно бывают системы, а не фреймворки, и дурак сам по себе понаоставляет дыр в приложении.